# javascript conditional operator format text

Tags: javascript, regex, format, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I am trying to conditionally format text data either 'red' or 'black' depending on whether it contains the character "-". The text is generated as a file and is an 'include' in the .shtml file.

Can you use a Regex pattern test in a conditional operator?

What am I doing wrong?

```
function colourful(a,b,c)
{
    var colour, pat, place,label,linkto;
    pat=new RegExp("-");
    place= a;
    label= b;
    linkto=c;
    colour=pat.test(label)?"red":"black";
    document.getElementById(place).innerHTML=label.fontcolor(colour);
    document.getElementById(place).href=linkto;
}
```

Example function calls;

```
colourful("in_the_document","£1,199.09","profit.shtml");
colourful("in_the_document","-£1,199.09","profit.shtml");
```

Comment: It looks like your RegExp comparison is correct. Could there be a different problem? What exactly is the problem you see?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`yourstring.indexOf("-")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to test if a string contains a certain string/character. If it return `-1` the string did not contain the character, otherwise it will return the index of the first occurence.

I guess your code would be:

```
colour = label.indexOf("-") === -1 ? "red" : "black";
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Christofer Eliasson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888105/1529630) said, you can use indexOf.
But if you want to use `RegExp`, you have [`search`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp):

```
colour = label.search(/-/) === -1 ? "red" : "black";
```

And it works with strings too:

```
colour = label.search("-") === -1 ? "red" : "black";
```

But `test()` should work too. I have tried your code and it works for me.